# How can take a dll from a game and inject it into gameplay?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, dll-injection, cheat-engine

Basically the game i am playing has a studio which lets you create games so it has toolbox that lets you insert blocks and more

How can I take this toolbox DLL and inject it into the game?

in normal gameplay there are no toolboxes, so what I wanna do is take the toolbox from the studio and insert it into the gameplay

there is a studio and a normal gameplay, in the studio there are tools which are useful and I want to take these put them in DLL and inject them in normal gameplay so I can use them in normal too

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible since the "toolbox" depends on a lot of functions at specific addresses etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have seen this happen, someone had made a dll for a specific game which had a creator mode he took the toolbox and injected the Dll and the toolbox was ingame please if you know anything tell me. This has something to do with reverse engineering I think but I don't know where to start or how exactly to do this

Comment: So you could reverse engineer the toolbox (with something free like ghidra, there are many tutorials on youtube) to extract the nessersarry functions or learn how they work etc. But this would be a very tedious process. Maybe you are lucky and some debug symbols are included, but thats probably not the cast.